# jQuery Datepicker, display 2 differently datepickers on same page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, datepicker

I am using a the jQuery [Datepicker][1] in a website. I am having trouble displaying 2 datepickers on the same page in different ways.

One which will only display once you click the text box, and once you select your date it disappears. 
Second I would like to display inline, but I cannot control one with out the other messing up.

I need help finding a work around so I can use 2 datepickers in a different way on the same page. I tried giving the second a separate id but that didn't work.

My first Date picker code:

```
<script> <!-- Datepicker -->
$(function() {
$( ".datepicker" ).datepicker();
});
</script>

<input type="text" class="search-input datepicker" placeholder="Check-In">

<input type="text" class="search-input datepicker" placeholder="Check-Out">
```

Here is my second Date picker code:

```
<script>
$(function() {
$( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker({
  numberOfMonths: 3,
  showButtonPanel: true
});
});
</script>

<p><input type="text" id="datepicker2"></p>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply give each text box a unique ID, then use that to create the datepicker. You can then put whichever options you want inside each `datepicker()` call:

```
$(function() 
{
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
});
```

HTML:

```
<p><input type="text" id="datepicker1"></p>
<div id="datepicker2"></div>
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/leetaylor/7K6k5/1/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I want one to display inline, and the other to display when I click the text box.

Comment: Thanks Lee; Legend! :P

Comment: No worries Luke. I see you're in Bournemouth. I work for a company in B'mouth (although I'm not based there)...

Answer (score 1):

I've done it before, my solution:

```
<script> <!-- Datepicker -->
$(function() 
{
    $( "#datepicker1" ).datepicker();
    $( "#datepicker2" ).datepicker();
});
</script>

<input type="text" class="search-input datepicker" placeholder="Check-In">

<input type="text" class="search-input datepicker2" placeholder="Check-Out">
```

Maybe there's any better solution?

Comment: I already have a check in and check out. My second datepicker is going to be used for an availability calendar. Thats why the other needs to be displayed inline. I think my question is a little confusing.

Comment: I don't understand, so this second datepicker displayed statically? Or You need to pick it? If it is, why You want 2 different datepicker?

Comment: Yeh my question is confusing. I have Check in and Check out datepickers in a search bar, I call these together Datepicker 1. The second datepicker is for seeing what the availability of a room is, so is it booked or not? I need this second datepicker to display inline, as it has its own section on the page. currently I cannot get just Datepicker 2 to display inline with out it messing up Datepicker 1. I hope that makes sense. :D

Comment: edited original to show the datepicker 2 script actually shows 3 months unlike datepicker 1.

Comment: Nevermind, I don't give You right answer. I get it now, You want create a calendar that always showed up and a calendar that in textbox :)